# Remove even numbers from array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Hello i'm trying for about 2 hours to create a program which will remove even numbers from a dinamyc allocated array(with malloc)in c.Can somebody help me with some tips or create the code.

p.s. this is my first topic here, so feel free to give me some tips about how to correctly post a qustion.

Comment: What do you have so far? Help means correcting your mistakes, so that you can learn from them. Doing somebody else's work for them helps nobody

Comment: @AnoopKanyan That's C++ not C

Comment: Show the code that you have.

Comment: @Gabriel Please don't hate me, but you shouldn't ask for help if you don't really show us that you need it. Is there any reason, why you don't show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you already allocated dynamically an array of n elements and initialized it.

In this case the function that removes elements with even values can look the following way

```
size_t remove_even( int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t m = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            if ( i != m ) a[m] = a[i];
            ++m;
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

It can be called the following way

```
size_t m = remove_even( p, n );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
printf( "\n" );
```

where p is the pointer to your dynamically allocated array of n elements.

The function actually removes nothing. It simply moves odd elements to the beginning of the array.

You can then use standard C function `realloc` to delete physically the removed elements.

For example

```
int *tmp = realloc( p, m * sizeof( int ) );

if ( tmp != NULL ) p = tmp;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t remove_even( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t m = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            if ( i != m ) a[m] = a[i];
            ++m;
        }
    }

    return m;
}

#define N   10

int main( void )
{
    int *a = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i] = i;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    size_t m = remove_even( a, N );

    int *tmp = realloc( a, m * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL ) a = tmp;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    free( a );
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things which you need to check before you try to code something, but I see that there is no code which you showed use.

SO is not a tutorial site, so this means that you should show us some code which actually does compile and ask here if there are some problems with that code.

Any way until than, this code should give you an Idea about how to check if a Number is `odd` or `even`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int n;

    printf("Enter an integer:>  ");
    if((scanf("%d", &n)) != 1){
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (n%2 == 0){
        printf("Even\n");
    }else{
        printf("Odd\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The whole story here is not about checking if Numbers inside an Array are `odd` or `even`, is about to find a way to check if a number is `odd` or `even` and only then you should check if inside that array there are `odd` or `even` numbers. I hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to remove even numbers from an array in C is to create a new array of all odd elements starting from 1 to the maximum element present in the original array and then compare the original array and odd elements array (and do intersection) and put it in another array with same elements present in both arrays.

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int a[20],n,i,max,j,k=0,l=0;
printf("enter limit of array ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("enter the elements ");

for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

max=a[0];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (a[i]>max){
        max=a[i];
    }
}
int b[max],c[n],count=0;

for (j=2;j<=max;j=j+2){
    c[k++]=j;
    count++;
}
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<count;j++){
        if (a[i]==c[j])
        b[l++]=a[i];
    }
}
for (i=0;i<count;i++){
    printf("%d ",b[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```