# Deleting an even number in an array and shift the elements

Tags: c++, arrays, shift

I'm trying to write a code where there is a research of even numbers and then it deletes the even numbers and then shifts all the other elements.

**i** is for offset and are the actual position of the elements in the array.

**k** is the position of the even number in the array.

```
int k;
for(i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(Array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
       for(k=i+1; k < N; k++)
       {
            Array[k-1] = Array[k];
       }
       N--;
    }
}
```

**Array=[2,10,3,5,8,7,3,3,7,10]** the even numbers should be removed, but a 10 
stays in the **Array=[10,3,5,7,3,3,7].**

Now is more than 3 hours that I'm trying to figure out what's wrong in my code.

Comment: This is accomplished with your array, a single "read" pointer, a single "write" pointer, and a single for-loop.  Anything beyond that is unnecessary. Otherwise you're needlessly copying the same elements over and over again. And fyi, the final length of you're reduced array is `(wptr - Array)`, where `wptr` is the write pointer you've been managing along the way.

Comment: `std::transform` might come in handy to accomplish this.

Comment: How is `Array` defined? You don't seem to delete any element in it

Comment: So without using the k variable?

Comment: The Array in the specific is an Int Array and the N is how much space the user uses. In fact the actual array is `int Array[100];` but the N limits the space that the user can access `int N; N=10;`.

Comment: The answer below covers using vectors, but if you *need* to use arrays, [here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901207/remove-even-numbers-from-array-in-c).

Comment: The problems is that I can't use the "easy" codes

Comment: read again comment above from WhozCraig ... then step away from keyboard and think ... only one for loop ... inside loop check if element is even ... if even then update your AvailablePointer to index of this even number element  ... on good non even number move value into array index matching your AvailablePointer ... that is IT you are done

Comment: Thank you Scott!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be some sort of homework or school assignment.  So what's the actual problem with the posted code?

It is that when you remove an even number at index `i`, you put the number that used to be at index `i + 1` down into index `i`.  Then you continue the outer loop iteration, which will check index `i + 1`, which is the number that was at the original `i + 2` position in the array.  So the number that started out at `Array[i + 1]`, and is now in `Array[i]`, is never checked.

A simple way to fix this is to decrement `i` when you decrement `N`.

Answer (score 1):

Though already answered, I fail to see the reason people are driving this through a double for-loop, repetitively moving data over and over, with each reduction.

I completely concur with all the advice about using containers. Further, the algorithms solution doesn't require a container (you *can*  use it on a native array), but containers still make it easier and cleaner. That said...

I described this algorithm in general-comment above. you don't need nested loops fr this. You need a read pointer and a write pointer. *that's it*.

```
#include <iostream>

size_t remove_even(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int *rptr = arr, *wptr = arr;

    while (n-- > 0)
    {
        if (*rptr % 2 != 0)
            *wptr++ = *rptr;
        ++rptr;
    }
    return (wptr - arr);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 2,10,3,5,8,7,3,3,7,10 };
    size_t n = remove_even(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);

    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
3 5 7 3 3 7
```

If you think it doesn't make a difference, I invite you to fill an array with a million random integers, then try both solutions (the nested-for-loop approach vs. what you see above).

---

**Using `std::remove_if` on a native array.**

Provided only for clarity, the code above basically does what the standard algorithm `std::remove_if` does. All we need do is provide iterators (the array offsets and size will work nicely), and know how to interpret the results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 2,10,3,5,8,7,3,3,7,10 };
    auto it = std::remove_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
                             [](int x){ return x%2 == 0; });

    for (size_t i=0; i<(it - arr); ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Same results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::vector` and the standard function `std::erase_if` + the vectors `erase` function to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> Array = {2, 10, 3, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 7, 10};

    auto it = std::remove_if(
        Array.begin(),
        Array.end(),
        [](int x) { return (x & 1) == 0 && x != 10; }
    );

    Array.erase(it, Array.end());

    for(int x : Array) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
3
5
7
3
3
7
10
```

Edit: Doing it the hard way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int Array[] = {2, 10, 3, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 7, 10};
    size_t N = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(int);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N;) {
        if((Array[i] & 1) == 0 && Array[i] != 10) {
            for(size_t k = i + 1; k < N; ++k) {
                Array[k - 1] = Array[k];
            }
            --N;
        } else
            ++i; // only step i if you didn't shift the other values down
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << Array[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Or simpler:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int Array[] = {2, 10, 3, 5, 8, 7, 3, 3, 7, 10};
    size_t N = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(int);
    size_t k = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if((Array[i] & 1) || Array[i] == 10) {
            // step k after having saved this value 
            Array[k++] = Array[i];
        }
    }
    N = k;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << Array[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I should use only the "simple" code, like movements and shifting. I also tried to use this code like this but my teacher refused that and asked to make it without easy codes; and for this I'm stuck with that.

Comment: @VikSn0w I see. Added a version for that too.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic solution in C++ would be to use a STL algorithm.

This example use a C-style array.

```
int Array[100] = {2,10,3,5,8,7,3,3,7,10};
int N = 10;

// our remove_if predicate
auto removeEvenExceptFirst10 = [first10 = true](int const& num) mutable {
    if (num == 10 && first10) {
        first10 = false;
        return false;
    }

    return num % 2 == 0;
};

auto newN = std::remove_if(
    std::begin(Array), std::begin(Array) + N,
    removeEvenExceptFirst10
);

N = std::distance(std::begin(Array), newN);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5cdad26321417ea)

Comment: the OP said solution must only use plain array and no modern techniques

Comment: @ScottStensland well, this uses plan array